# Daemon thread with loop in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

As soon as the main() thread ends then the Daemon thread should also end. In the case of simple if-else, it is printing the value but in the case of a while loop, it is not printing any value.

In both cases, it shouldn't print anything because the main() thread ends so the Daemon thread shouldn't execute.

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        // In case of while loop it is not printing anything
        /*
        int count = 1;
        while(count<=20){
            System.out.println(count++);
        }
        */

        //In this case it is printing "It is Daemon"  WHY ???
        if(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()){
            System.out.println("It is Daemon");
        }else{
            System.out.println("it is not Daemon");
        }
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyThread d = new MyThread();
        d.setDaemon(true);
        d.start();
    }
}
```

Why it is working differently in both cases ??

Not able to understand why it is working different in both the cases

Comment: It's a race condition. The daemon thread will not keep the application alive, but it isn't terminated immediately.

Comment: @matt What does it mean?? I am just starting with it.

Comment: Essentially, you've told java to start a thread, and it goes through the process of starting the thread, then the main loop finishes, and jvm starts to tear down. The thread you started starts doing what it has been instructed to do. By the time the jvm instructs the thread to stop, the thread might have done some work.

Comment: @Mar-Z Did you not see `System.out.println(count++);` ?

Answer (score 3):

As said already in the comments, the observed behaviour is due to a race condition: who is faster – the main thread or the deamon thread?

For the CPU, the few milliseconds (or nanoseconds?) between the execution of `d.start()` and the end of `main()` are eons – not to mention that the main thread is probably suspended after the execution of `d.start()`. This may give the deamon thread enough time to terminate *regularly* before it will be killed in the second case.

In case of the `while` loop, the thread may be suspended itself after the first `System.out.println` and then it will be killed while suspended, because the program is terminated. Obviously the buffers for `System.out` will not be flushed before the termination of the program (although `println()` should flush always).

But it is always difficult to say exactly when a task switch occurs; maybe you get some output even from the while loop when you just try often enough.